# Erro ao abrir projeto app Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragment

Ao abrir o projeto do app Android de um amigo meu no meu PC  ,  me deparei com esses erros.

Como resolvo isso ?

imagens da tela :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código do   Grandle ( modulo app )   :

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.leva.user"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url uri('mint-plugin-repo-5.1.0')
        }
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //For error logcat
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.0.3'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.materialshadowninepatch:materialshadowninepatch:0.6.5'
    compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.splunk:mint-android-sdk:5.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.citux:datetimepicker:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: manda o código do teu gradle do módulo app

Comment: Por favor, melhora as imagens, ponha ao menos todas na horizontal para ajudar na leitura

Comment: ok . corrigi e adicionei mais informaçoes

Comment: @LucasDuete ok.  Eu melhorei as imagens e adicionei o código.

Comment: Pesquisa a versão mais recente disso "android.enableAapt2", pode ser uma biblioteca ou algum recurso de alguma biblioteca que o projeto está utilizando. Quando encontrar a versão atual da biblioteca substitui no gradle. 

Apaga o cache do projeto (File -> Invalidade Caches), reinicia o projeto e faz o build novamente para o projeto baixar novamente todas as bibliotecas.